# Minecraft: I fished out a rod in Bedrock edition minecraft and I am wondering the odds of this pull

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[image: God Rod]

I pulled this out with a unenchanted fishing rod.
My friends didn’t believe me and the ones who did said it is about 1 in a hundred million.
This fishing rod has un breaking 3 Luck of the sea3, mending, and Lure3.
Note: This was before mending2 existed. I beleive that this is the best fishing rod possible at this time. It was pulled up Jan17, 2020. (Bedrock Edition)

Comment: Mending II doesnt and never existed

Comment: Mending 2 will come in the next Minecraft bedrock update. Why else would it say mending I? I also read the patch notes.

Comment: even if it does, **every single enchantment says a level at the end even single-level ones.** What about Silk Touch? It says *Silk Touch I*. Silk Touch II doesn't exist. Also it has said *Mending I* since 1.9.

Comment: Ok. U clearly know ur sheit better than me. Just wondering, do you have an estimate on how rare this pull is? I think that it seems like a 1 in 100 mill pull.

Comment: I dont think its 1 in 100m but I have no idea

Comment: Probably about 1.8 percent